# Date Time create from format

Tags: php, datetime-format

I want to create date with specific format for e.g 03-20-2010 have a format of m-d-Y but date function do not understand this date and returns wrong date

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("03-20-2010"));
```

Above code is returning wrong date, what is the reason behind it and how to avoid wrong result? Few formats that I want date function to recognize are "Y/m/d" , "m/d/Y" , "F d, Y" , "M d, Y".

Comment: The reason is simple. strtotime() is not a magic wand. It cannot tell if certain number is for month or day.

Comment: is there any custom implementation of strtotime taking format in parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strtotime won't recognize an American style ordering separated by '-', but if you use a '/' separator, it will work just fine.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', "03-20-2010")));
```

As Pekka notes, it's better if your code explicity declares the format you are using.

Answer (score 23):

Funnily enough, your question title contains the *exact* solution to the problem!

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). (Note: Requires PHP >= 5.3)

It allows you to specify the exact format of the date to expect, so there is none  of `strtotime()`s ambiguity / anglo-american bias.

This should work:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2010-03-20");
```

Comment: This function is for php greater than 5.3 and it is giving undefined function error for my version.

Comment: well answer was pretty obvious since it was in documentation but it was not applicable for most of the web applications currently running.

Comment: @Ayaz fair enough, I overlooked the 5.3 limitation and that renders it indeed unusable on most shared hosters at the moment. It is still rude to downvote a (technically still valid) answer without any comment, especially if you're the question asker who is being helped. A question is never only for yourself, it's for future generations who face the same issue. I don't care about the downvote, but I do care about the gesture. It really isn't good style. If you want answers from me in the future, don't do it any more.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the timestamp with mktime and use that timestamp

```
$exact_time = "03-20-2010";
$exploded_et = explode("-",$exact_time);
$date = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$exploded_et[0],$exploded_et[1],$exploded_et[2]));
```