# change date format in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this view

```
<?PHP 
    $no = 0;
    foreach ($dt as $key => $row) { 
        $no++;
    ?>
<td style="text-align:center;"> <?=$row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA;?> </td>
```

with result

```
21/11/2018  0:00:00
```

What I want is to change the format into

```
21 December 2018
```

Comment: This has been asked many times google search how to change date format codeigniter

Comment: @Mr.ED yes I've search it before and I've tried it also but none is working

Comment: and what did you try faiz ? you didn't show anything what you tried - because as ED already said - this was asked and answered so many times here ... e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542162/date-time-create-from-format#3542182

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Time create from format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542162/date-time-create-from-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$date = "21/11/2018  0:00:00";
echo date('d F Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)))
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0214-fq7u)

> **FYI:** with this formation you can use this for saving in DB date which has `/` and MySQL won't throw an error with invalid date format.

Comment: Yes it works BUT there is a strange things. I'm using this code <?php echo date('d F Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA))); ?> and it give different result. In 28/04/2012  0:00:00 it show 28-Apr-12. AND for 10/12/2018  0:00:00 it show 10 December 2018. How to fix this and the correct one is 10 December 2018 format.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert that with this sample

```
$date=date_create("21-11-2018  0:00:00");
echo date_format($date,"d F y"); //it will echo 21 November 18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$str =$dt;
  echo date('"d F Y"', strtotime($str));
?>
```

Comment: Is there any need to duplicate existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

imho the best way here is the use of the `DateTime::createFromFormat` function, try the following

```
<?php
$no = 0;
foreach ($dt as $key => $row) { 

    $objTanggalKadaluarsa = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA);
    $no++;
?>
<td style="text-align:center;"> <?=$objTanggalKadaluarsa->format('d F Y');?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (my format data is 2018-09-03 16:12:40)

```
$month = array("January",
"February",
"March",
"April",
"May",
"June",
"July",
"August",
"September",
"October",
"November",
"December"
);

echo substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,8,2).' '.$month[substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,5,2)-1].' '.(substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,0,4)).' | '.substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,-8);
```

Comment: this is working actually. It give result 28 April 2012 | 00:00:00. But how to remove | 00:00:00 ? If I remove .' | '.substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,-8) it give two different result, 10 December 2018 and 28-Apr-12 format. The correct one should be 10 December 2018 format

Comment: try this
        echo (substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,0,2)).' '.$month[(substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,3,2))].' '.substr($row->TANGGAL_KADALUARSA,6,4);